# select top 2 rows in each category

Tags: sql-server

Is that possible to select two rows in each category

I have a table like below

```
 DECLARE @temptable TABLE 
 ( id int IDENTITY(1,1) 
 ,name nvarchar(20) NULL 
 ,category int NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @temptable ( name ,category)
VALUES 
( 'nikhil1' ,1)
, ('sumesh1' ,2)
, ('sumesh2' ,2)
, ('nikhil2' ,1)
, ('nikhil3',1)
, ('sumesh3' ,2)


SELECT *
FROM @temptable t
ORDER BY t.id ASC
```

i want the result as below

> ```
> | id | Name  | category|
> |----------------------|
> | 1  |nikhil1|  1      |
> | 2  |nikhil2|  1      |
> | 3  |sumesh1|  2      |
> | 4  |sumesh2|  2      |
> ```

All thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
;WITH CategoriesCTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY category ORDER BY name) AS rn
    FROM   @temptable
)
SELECT *
FROM CategoriesCTE t
WHERE rn<=2
```

A bit of background on that: We are defining a CTE which will have an extra column that for each category will give an incremental number on its items. That number will be zeroed in each change of category. This is enforced by the `PARTITION BY` clause in the `ROW_NUMBER`. Then we are filtering the results to get all products which got the first two numbers in each category.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to a CTE is a derived table, which will effectively do the same thing...

```
SELECT id, name, category
FROM (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY name) AS rn
        FROM @temptable
     ) tbl
WHERE rn<=2
```